# My computer freezes very often when I watch videos on youtube, or if I browse the web

Tags: graphics, intel

My computer freezes very often when I watch videos on youtube, or if I browse the web.
I think that i have a problem with the driver of my graphic card ...

Sony Vaio SVS1311F3E/W

Intel Core i5-3210M à 2,5 GHz (3.1 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost technology).

Memory cache      3 Mo.

Chipset     Intel HM76 Express.

RAM 4 Go DDR3.

Hard drive   500 Go SATA.

Graphic card Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Specify the browser you use, and I guess , you need to install Flash properly ,seems flash problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: These instructions are obsolete. The fix has entered the default repositories. If you are still experiencing freezing, your problem is different from the OP's. Please open a new question about it (after reading [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes), of course).

---

[Known bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/linux/+bug/999910)

Solution:

1. Open Update Manager
2. Click the **Settings** button
3. Check the box **Pre-released updates**
4. Click the **Check** button in Update Manager
5. Install the updates
6. Reboot

Problem solved.

Optional:

- Uncheck **Pre-released updates** in Update Manager settings to avoid getting potentially unstable updates in the future

Answer (score 0):

Run a memory test. You will have to select "memory test" from your Grub menu. If it is not available, install the `memtest` package first. Usually, the Grub menu can be revealed by holding the left Shift key during boot.

Edit: Look, if you are voting this down, at least explain to me why. Memory failure could very well be the cause of such random lockups.